# How to identify the end of the array programmatically

Tags: ruby, arrays

For an array `[1, 2, 3, 4],` how do I know that I am on the final element of the array while I am processing each  element.

```
arr = [1, 2, 3, 4]
arr.each do |a|

...

end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
arr = [1, 2, 3, 4]
l = arr.length - 1
arr.each_with_index do |a, i|
  if i == l
    ...
  else
    ...
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

```
arr = [1, 2, 3, 4]
arr.each_with_index do |el, idx|
  if idx == arr.length - 1
    # you're on the last element
  end
end
```

Comment: I don't think it is efficient if you evaluate `arr.length` and further calculate `- 1` for every item in `arr`.

Comment: Did you measure the difference?

Comment: @sawa I suspect `.length` is O(1), not O(n).